# How can i add menubutton on tableview header

Tags: java, javafx

I have a `tableView`, I am changing the table using some controls in the `MenuButton` for each column. Now i want to place the buttons to each columns header.

How do I make it?

- *Columns variable: `TableColumn[] tableColumns;`*
- *Menus variable: `MenuButton[] menuButtons;`*
- *column count: `int column;`*

How do I merge `menuButtons` and `tableColumns` ?

Comment: What exactly you whant to do? You can add a Button to a TableColumn with  tableColumn.setGraphic(button);

Comment: yes its my solution, It does not think without knowing, please answer that :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a Button to a TableColumn with:

```
tableColumn.setGraphic(button);
```